# Is it possible to concatenate several commands in python eval()?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to `eval(open('file1').readline())` and write this line to another file like: `eval(open('file1').readline().write('file2'))` but this obviously does not work, because one must open `file2` before writting on it.

So is it possible to concatenate commands in `eval()`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the save the result of `eval()` in the second file?

Comment: Why would you want to `eval` the return value of `write`? I guess you want to `eval` the line you read, but then you should do that, and do the file writing after you have `eval`'ed the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the `eval` expression you have inside another function call that writes its result to another file:

```
open('file2', 'w').write(eval(open('file1').readline()))
```

But it's generally bad style to pack so much stuff into one line like this. It's usually better to write slightly more verbose code that's easier to understand and debug. For instance, if you get an exception from one of the function calls, it will be hard to tell which part of the line caused the problem.

Here's a multiple-statement version that I think is better in almost every way:

```
with open('file1') as file1:
    input_line = file1.readline()
output_line = eval(input_line)
with open('file2', 'w') as file2:
    file2.write(output_line)
```

If you get an exception from part of this code, it will be immediately obvious which part caused it, since the separate function calls are all on separate lines. It's also better about closing the files it opens, using `with` statements to do it as soon as the files are not needed (the end of each of the indented blocks). The one-line version relied on the Python garbage collector to close the files, which might take longer than expected.